Response status code does not indicate success error when reading a single document in Cosmos DB
I'm using the new Cosmos DB SDK for .NET to read a single item/document from my Cosmos DB database.
I'm trying to read a document that I know exists in a database and container that also exist. I know they exist because I see them in the Data Explorer view in the portal. When I run my query, I get the following error:

Response status code does not indicate success: NotFound (404);
Substatus: 0; ActivityId: 3483bb5a-139e-457b-9a35-910bf66345eb;
Reason: ( Errors : [   "Resource Not Found. Learn more:
https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-tsg-not-found" ] );

Also, in my code, I make sure both the database and container exist using the following code snippets.
private Database _database;
private Container _container;

...

if(_database == null)
   _database = await _client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(_databaseName);

...

if(_container == null)
   _container = await _database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(collectionId, "/categoryId");

My question is how do I know what this error is referring to? Is it the database or the container or the actual item that I'm querying? I know all of them exist so clearly I'm making a mistake somewhere and it would be very helpful if I knew what this error is indicating as missing.
BTW, categoryId is a property that exists in all the documents I store in my Cosmos DB and I set it as the partitionKey for my database i.e. /categoryId
Here's my wrapper method that I use to read a single document of type T:
public async Task<T> GetDocument<T>(string collectionId, int categoryId, string id)
{
    try
    {
        if (_container == null)
            await GetContainer(collectionId);

        // If container is still null, throw error
        if(_container == null)
           throw new Exception("Unable to get/create container!");

        var item = await _container.ReadItemAsync<T>(
            id: id,
            partitionKey: new PartitionKey(categoryId.ToString()));
        return item;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception(e.Message);
    }
}


Are you sure the document you can see in data explorer has categoryid contained as a string rather than a number?

@MartinSmith You are RIGHT! That was the problem. I thought I needed to convert int value to string for partition key to accept the value. When I left it as an int value, the query worked fine now and returned the document. THANK YOU!!!
